# Using Python Script and Model Builder to create JSON output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service

So I have a script that creates a selection based off of a user's entry and stores select attributes of that entry into a python dictionary.

Ideally, the user would give a street segment ID  and the code would return the IDs of the nearest features within a certain distance with specific attributes, and store all of this into a dictionary. This dictionary is then converted into JSON using (arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, json.dumps()).

The goal is to publish this as a processioning service. The code works and so I tried to recreate this via model builder in ArcToolBox. This also runs too but when uploaded as a service, it fails.

Is there anyone that can give insight to why this is happening? I am assuming that I may need to re work my model.

Attached is the resulting Server messages. The chosen ID is 5705. Which again, works perfectly when just running the script and when running the script as a toolbox on ArcMap. However on the server it fails.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the actual error or expand on "when upload as a service, it fails"?

Comment: @KHibma please see additional post above. Thank you.